# Specifying Climb rate in the Boeing 747-400 FMC

Tags: flight-simulator

In the Aerowinx Precision Simulator PSX documentation for the FMC, I do not see how one can program a climb rate after takeoff.

I'm more interested however in the actual airplane. Suppose after clean-up, I want to maintain 500 FPM, is this something that I can only do via intervention with the V/S switch on the MCP, or is this programmatically achievable in the FMC?

Typically, at 400 AGL, VNAV engages with VNAV-SPD and THR-REF pitch and A/T modes, but the fixed climb thrust only allows the use of elevators to maintain the commanded pitch for airspeed. However, if I hit the V/S button and scroll to the target climbrate, then the A/T mode that automatically switches to SPD will control airspeed with thrust, and I can chase the horizontal FD bar to control climbrate with elevators. What I want to know is whether I can program this into the FMC, such that at the acceleration height or Flaps 5 setting, the engaged pitch mode automatically changes from VNAV-SPD to V/S. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

VNAV has nothing to do with Climb Rate - if you want a VS use VS mode, else use VNAV or FLCH.
VNAV is trying to get the airplane as high as possible as soon as possible, so that it can cruise in the thin air for as long as possible.  "I want 500fpm" is incompatible with this, that's why you have the different vertical modes.
RAC

Comment: Thanks, but I’m well aware that VNAV does not control vertical speed, which is precisely why I was asking about whether the V/S functionality could be programmed into the FMC.

Comment: In fairness, I can see how the 2nd paragraph of my question might have been a bit confusing, so I’ve rephrased it to clarify my precise intent.

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar but still, why would you want to do that? For climb it is both more efficient, and safer, to set climb power and maintain speed with pitch, that is the FLCH mode.

Comment: It's not about me specifically wanting to do it - and frankly I wouldn't want to. My question is quite simply - out of academic interest - whether this can be programmed into the FMC. By the way, there are some operating procedures where at MGTOW, a climb rate of 500 FPM is suggested up to the clean maneuvering speed of 250 to 260 KIAS (VREF +100). See page 10 of the PDF at this link: https://kingla.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/boeing747-400flightmanual.pdf.

Comment: As you will note, they don't suggest using V/S either, but setting climb power and accepting whatever they get between 500 -- 1000 FPM.  I'm just curious as to whether there is any feature in the FMC where it accepts a climbrate specification.

Comment: The FMC is about *planning* the flight, and you wouldn't normally plan to use VS - that's generally used to rescue a plan that's not working.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the clarification. A quick follow-up: Does FL CH eliminate all altitude constraints if  a higher altitude is selected in the Altitude window?